# How to know if value of cookie change using Nextjs?

Tags: next.js, cookies, server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HuWu.png)fellow programmers. I'm experiencing an issue with the cookies in the next/headers. What I want to do is show a link or a user icon. To put it simply, I'm saving my backend response in next-cookies, checking to see if cookies have length equal to 1, and then either displaying the link or the user icon. The screenshot I've attached demonstrates how I'm accomplishing this, however when the response is set to cookies, the user icon is not displayed. Instead, it displays a link—until I refresh the page, at which point the user icon is displayed. When cookies are updated, that is when I want to see. I would be appreciative if someone could assist me with this issue.

I tried many things which I can but I can't.